# SQL - Table sort by events

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| userid | events |
+--------+--------+
|   1    |  blog  |
|   2    |  blog  |
|   1    |  site  |
|   1    |  move  |
|   2    |  move  |
|   3    |  blog  |
|   2    |  blog  |
+--------+--------+
```

I want to display all users who participated in all the events that I passed as parameters.

Example: All users who participated in "blog" AND "move"

Knowing that a user can participate multiple times to an event.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid
FROM table_name
WHERE events = 'blog'
AND userid IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT userid
    FROM table_name
    WHERE events = 'move'
)
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4504c/2)

Answer (score 5):

```
select userid
from your_table
where events in ('blog','move')
group by userid
having count(distinct events) = 2
```

If you have 3 events to check then use

```
having count(distinct events) = 3
```

Comment: If you have a user that participated in 2 events, your select will get the users even if the events are not 'blog' or 'move'. You can replace 'blog' or 'move' by anything in your in condition, for example 'aaa', the result will be the same.

Comment: I disagree. But you can build a SQLFiddle and prove me wrong.

Comment: My analysis was a little wrong. But the main idea was here: the solution you provided does not work. Here is my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4504c/1). The right analysis: if a user participated to one of the two events (blog or move) but two times, your select will get this user.

Comment: If your table design allows duplicates (which not seems to be the case for the OP) then just use `having count(distinct events) = 2` instead

Comment: Ok, that works. But there's a duplicate in the table: userid 2 participated two times in the event 'blog'. And it's specified that a user can participate multiple time in a event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select a.userid
from tablename a join tablename b
on a.userid = b.userid
where a.events='blog' and b.events='move';
```